# Asynchronous loading of CSS file (prototype default.css)

Tags: css, layout, prototype, magento-1.9

I decided to test my site for speed (google check speed).
And he caught this warning:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>   Your page has 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in
>   rendering your page. None of the above-the-fold content on your page
>   could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load.
>   Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the
>   critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML. Optimize
>   CSS Delivery of the following:
>
> ```
> https://www.example.com/js/prototype/windows/themes/default.css
> ```

I implement this file in the layout:

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
 </reference>
```

And this css :

```
.overlay_dialog {
    background-color: #666666;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity: 0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay___invisible__ {
  background-color: #666666;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.dialog_nw {
    width: 9px;
    height: 23px;
    background: transparent url(default/top_left.gif) no-repeat 0 0;        
}

.dialog_n {
    background: transparent url(default/top_mid.gif) repeat-x 0 0;  
    height: 23px;
}

.dialog_ne {
    width: 9px;
    height: 23px;
    background: transparent url(default/top_right.gif) no-repeat 0 0;       
}

.dialog_e {
    width: 2px;
    background: transparent url(default/center_right.gif) repeat-y 0 0; 
}

.dialog_w {
    width: 2px;
    background: transparent url(default/center_left.gif) repeat-y 0 0;      
}

.dialog_sw {
    width: 9px;
    height: 19px;
    background: transparent url(default/bottom_left.gif) no-repeat 0 0;         
}

.dialog_s {
    background: transparent url(default/bottom_mid.gif) repeat-x 0 0;       
    height: 19px;
}

.dialog_se {
    width: 9px;
    height: 19px;
    background: transparent url(default/bottom_right.gif) no-repeat 0 0;            
}

.dialog_sizer {
    width: 9px;
    height: 19px;
    background: transparent url(default/sizer.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
    cursor:se-resize;   
}

.dialog_close {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: transparent url(default/close.gif) no-repeat 0 0;           
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:8px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:2000;
}

.dialog_minimize {
    width: 14px;
    height: 15px;
    background: transparent url(default/minimize.gif) no-repeat 0 0;            
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:28px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:2000;
}

.dialog_maximize {
    width: 14px;
    height: 15px;
    background: transparent url(default/maximize.gif) no-repeat 0 0;            
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:49px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:2000;
}

.dialog_title {
    float:left;
    height:14px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
}

.dialog_content {
    overflow:auto;
    color: #DDD;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color:#123;
}

.top_draggable, .bottom_draggable {
  cursor:move;
}

.status_bar {
  font-size:12px;
}
.status_bar input{
  font-size:12px;
}

.wired_frame {
    display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px #000 dashed;
}

/* DO NOT CHANGE THESE VALUES*/
.dialog {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.dialog table.table_window  { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border-spacing: 0; 
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.dialog table.table_window td , .dialog table.table_window th { 
  padding: 0; 
}

.dialog .title_window {
  -moz-user-select:none;
}
```

May be anybody know what this warning can be and how to spill it. Perhaps assisting the asynchronous loading.

## Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you do not use @import anywhere in your CSS files and making sure you have a rel attribute set as this can cause render blocking.

You can also combine all your other CSS files into one and you can even go further and **minimize** your CSS files online by removing blank spaces, but keep a backup of the original nested CSS as well.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>http://www.example.com/skin/OTHER-theme_name/css/skin.css</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```